# How to deploy Servlet project to some online server hosting

Tags: java, android, mysql, tomcat, servlets

I have zero experience on deploying my Servlet project to some real server. What I did were usually start the server locally and ping the IP to my Android device.

This only works locally. Let's say if I never start the server, the app won't works. I am starting to think about how to actually deploy the Servlet project into some free hosting so that I can access my app anywhere anytime without me starting the local server.

I have seen some tips saying export the project into `.war` and put it inside tomcat installation folder. But at the end of the day, you still need to start the local server in order for your app to access all the SQL queries inside the Servlet, am I right?

This is school project and I don't intend to purchase some server hosting. Any suggestion for free server hosting for `Servlet + MySQL` or any tips on how can I actually deploy it to become an 'online server'?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on your request:

1) Please don't ask for recommendations of libraries, services etc. on stack overflow.

2) Some of the mayor cloud players offer limited free resources - ask your favorite search engine

3) If it's a school project, maybe ask the teachers running your school network if they can help you out with that. Setting up a small server with MySQL, Apache, Tomcat seems like a fun project.

4) There's dynDNS and the sort out there, providing you with a network name for your home IP address - so you could route requests from the internet into your local server. Make sure you understand the security risks before following that path.

5) Building a .war and starting from that is the correct approach.